# div auto width, div fixed width, div auto width

Tags: html, css

Got a **fixed div of 40px** that i need to put **on the middle of two auto width div**

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div style="min-height:60px; width:auto fill left"></div>
          <div style="width:40px; min-height:60px;"></div>
          <div style="min-height:60px; width:auto fill right"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extremely common question, any ways try this out!

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 700px; /* .center and combined min-width we want for .left and .right */
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper > div {
    min-height: 100%; /* set to whatever height you want */
}
.left {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: -250px; /* half of .center */
}
.left > div {
    margin-right: 255px; /* half of .center with 5px extra padding */
}
.center {
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
.right {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin-left: -250px; /* half of .center */
}
.right > div {
    margin-left: 255px; /* half of .center with 5px extra padding */
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="left">
            <div>
                <p>Left column content.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <p>Center column content.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div>
                <p>Right column content.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akjpL

---

I didn't have time to explain what the above code does at the time I wrote it, so I'll give a brief explanation now.

`.left` and `.right` are both floated to their respective sides and set to equal a width of 50% of the page to sit exactly side by side, their margins are set to be the negative value of half of whatever we make `.center`. We then need to create child div's for each `.left` and `.right` and set their margins to positive of the same amount we set as the negative value for their parent div's plus some padding which you can play around with - as in the padding is added onto the margin. Now we have made room for `.center` to be in the middle, it's width will again be the positive total of the negative margins of `.left` and `.right`, we'll float it left and it will fit right in the middle! Any questions feel free to ask away!

Comment: my gosh thanks iv been looking for that all this day, im sorry my reputation is too low to upvote you but i accept that ! thanks again rly

Comment: That's okay, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `display: table;` on `.container`, `display: table-row;` on `.row` and `display: table-cell;` on the inner DIVs.

Comment: it is not working but i guess ill have to play with the table css thanks ill trick that tomorow